# Can before[Each] and after[Each] be async when using the BDD interface?

Tags: intern

Am I missing something or is it not possible for before[Each] and after[Each] to be async when using the BDD interface? I can get async test to run fine just not the setup parts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; return a promise from any of the setup methods in order to make them asynchronous.

Comment: Is there a reason why this.async is not available in these methods like 'it'?

Comment: The value of `this` inside a test is a Test object; the value of `this` inside a before/after/etc. is a Suite object. It’s not impossible to have an `async` function on suites, but it doesn’t exist currently since it wasn’t ever a use case that we needed.